# Before and after login, I want to use same URL but use different class based view

Tags: python, django

Before and after user login, URL is not changed in many websites. How should I implement this in Django? For example,
http://example.com (show login page) → login → http://example.com (show content list)

I want to use class based view for Login Page (auth_views.LoginView),
then after user login, use generic list View and different template.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

urlpatterns = [
path('', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='index.html'), name='index'),
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class UserIndexView(ListView):
    model = mymodel
    template_name = 'user_index.html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each URL can only be served by one view. Handling multiple actions (showing the index page and handling logins) on the same view will make it more complicated.

In Django, the usual approach is to use a separate URL for the login.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', UserIndexView.as_view(), name='index',
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
]
```

You can then use the [`LoginRequiredMixin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin). Anonymous users will be redirected from the homepage to the login page, then redirected back to the homepage after they have logged in.

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

from django.views.generic import ListView

class UserIndexView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = mymodel
    template_name = 'user_index.html'
```

Comment: Thank you. I now understand that the best and common way is to separete each actions in several URLs.